# C# - How to Create a Window using code only?

Tags: c#, winforms, window

So, I actually code in Java, but last week, I started with **C#** Programming,

Could someone maybe tell me how to **Create a Window**?

But I want to create it using **code ONLY**, without a Graphic Window Editor, like Visual basic.

Clear C# Code.

**Thanks**, to anyone who can answer!

**[image: C# Form]

Comment: Look into `Form1.Designer.cs`, that's how designer creates a form and what you have to do yourself otherwise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here you got a start point. (this is a console application) Just remember to add "system.windows.forms" to your reference in the project: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx
There are probably way! better ways to do this, but this is one of the ways.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace myform
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Form myform = new Form();
            Button mybutton = new Button()
            {
                Text = "Hello",
                Location = new System.Drawing.Point(10, 10)
            };
            mybutton.Click += (o, s) =>
            {
                MessageBox.Show("world");
            };

            myform.Controls.Add(mybutton);
            myform.ShowDialog();

            while (myform.Created)
            {

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also see @Sinatr comment